# Understanding my mistake with for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm new to C and I'm trying to practice my knowledge by doing programs by my own without the use of the internet. I'm stuck with a small and probably dumb mistake but i can't seem to understand what it is. I'm trying to build an hour glass but before i do so i need to understand printing triangles. I'm really going step by step with this and I have tried to understand my mistake for very long with this.
I have my code below and I'm trying to print j where i need j to print normally 12345 then 1234, 123 etc.. but when I use temp-- it skips by printing 123,1,1 and closes the program. 
Can somebody have a look at it and tell me what the problem with me second for loop?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
{
    int i,j,k,num, temp=0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    temp=num;

    for (i=1; i<=num; i++) // Step1: Take care of the rows --> check
   {
    for (j=1; j<=temp; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", j);
        temp-=1;

    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the expected output? what it actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You both increment `j` and decrement `temp` which leads to odd effects.  You probably don't want to decrement `temp`. Or you need to reset `temp` before the inner loop, rather than before the outer loop.

Or, indeed, you do not really need `temp` at all.  Here are two variants of the code, one creating a triangle growing, and one creating a triangle shrinking.  Neither needs `temp` (though `t-dn.c` could use a variable in place of the expression `num - i + 1`, but the compiler will probably handle that anyway — it is a basic optimization).

#### t-up.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i,j,num;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  for (i=1; i<=num; i++)
  {
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
      printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

#### t-dn.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i,j,num;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  for (i=1; i<=num; i++)
  {
    for (j=1; j<=num-i+1; j++)
      printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./t-up
Enter a number: 5
1
12
123
1234
12345
$ ./t-dn
Enter a number: 5
12345
1234
123
12
1
$
```

#### t-ok.c

Another variant, keeping the `temp` variable around:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i,j,num,temp;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  temp=num;

  for (i=1; i<=num; i++)
  {
    for (j=1; j<=temp; j++)
      printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");
    temp--;
  }
}
```

It produces the decreasing pyramid I believe you want.  It places the decrement outside the inner loop.

Comment: so should i only decrement j?

Comment: Possibly; it depends on what you're after...I think I'd expect the inner loop to be `for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)`, which would give you 1 on the first line, 12 on the second, 123 on the third, and so on.  If you want to count down (so, for example, 12345 on the first, then 1234, then 123, etc), then you adjust the conditions.

Comment: you probably want to decrement `temp` after the inner `for` loop, right in front of the last `printf`.

Comment: NB: all these toy programs are careless about checking that the `scanf()` statement successfully read a number.

Answer (score 1):

You're decrementing your j-loop condition within the j-loop. This means that every time you print a number, you also decrease the size of your loop (not at all what you want). To fix this, you need to move your temp-=1 from

```
for (i=1; i<=num; i++) // Step1: Take care of the rows --> check
{
for (j=1; j<=temp; j++)
{
    printf("%d", j);
    temp-=1;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

to

```
for (i=1; i<=num; i++) // Step1: Take care of the rows --> check
{
for (j=1; j<=temp; j++)
{
    printf("%d", j);
}
temp-=1;
printf("\n");
}
```

This decreases the size of your j-loop AFTER you've finished going through it, so you should wind up with the right amount of numbers.

You could even do away with your temporary variable by reversing the i-loop like such

```
for ( i = num ; i > 0 ; i-- ) {
    for ( j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ ) {
        printf("%d", j);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

for a simpler code.